# How to draw a new square every time "DrawObject()" is in the file

Tags: c#

So I have made a file reader and it reads every line in the file, i have a few commands that it will read and it works but this one wont work
When the file says "DrawObject()" 
it should do this:

```
            if (line.Contains("DrawObject()"))
            {
                r = new Rectangle();
                r.Width = 32;
                r.Height = 32;
                Invalidate();
            }
```

And it does draw the rectangle because in the paint event I put:

```
    private void TestScript_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g = e.Graphics;
        g.Clear(Color.White);

        if (dp == true)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, x, y, 32, 32);
        }

        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, r);

        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
```

and it draws the square (g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, r))
but i want to be able to draw multiple squares
and every time a square is drawn the player can change the squares X and Y values

These are the X and Y values the player can change in the file:

```
            if (line.Contains("ObjectX>"))
            {
                r.X = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(9));
            }

            if (line.Contains("ObjectY>"))
            {
                r.Y = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(9));
            }
```

EDIT OF CODE:

```
if (line.Contains("DrawObject()"))
{
    rectangles.Add(new Rectangle() { Width = 32, Height = 32 } );
    Invalidate();
}

if (line.Contains("ObjectX>"))
{
    Rectangle r = rectangles.Last();
    r.X = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(9));
    Invalidate();
}

if (line.Contains("ObjectY>"))
{
    Rectangle r = rectangles.Last();
    r.Y = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(9));
    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Well if you want to be able to draw multiple shapes, you're going to need to store that as state - whereas currently you appear to only have a *single* variable (`r`). Perhaps you should have a variable of type `List<Rectangle>` instead? Just remember that your `Paint` event handler should be able to redraw the complete UI - so it needs to have enough information to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw multiple rectangles you need to "store" them all and not only the last one - e.g. like this:

```
// instead of "private Rectangle r" I assume you have
private List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
```

And then during parsing:

```
if (line.Contains("DrawObject()"))
{
    rectangles.Add(new Rectangle() { Width = 32, Height = 32 });
    Invalidate();
}
```

...and painting:

```
private void TestScript_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    g = e.Graphics;
    g.Clear(Color.White);

    if (dp == true)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, x, y, 32, 32);
    }

    foreach (Rectangle r in rectangles)
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, r);

    DoubleBuffered = true;
}
```

...and to move the last one:

```
if (line.Contains("ObjectX>"))
{
    Rectangle r = rectangles.Last();
    r.X = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(9));
}
if (line.Contains("ObjectY>"))
{
    Rectangle r = rectangles.Last();
    r.Y = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(9));
}
```

NOTE: You should check here if there is already a rectangle set to avoid an error.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.

Comment: It draws the Rectangle when I type "DrawObject()" but the "ObjectX>" and "ObjectY>" doesnt seem to work

Comment: @VocableTheory: Have you tried adding an `Invalidate()` there too?

Comment: no but know that you mentioned it that would make more sense.

Comment: I keep getting an error when I run it that says "Sequence contains no elements", I think its do to the  `.Last()` part because I want to move each individual object, so for example in the script the developer made to move two different objects in two different places, the `.Last()` part would mean the very last rectangle so I can basically only move the last rectangle. I think that's whats happenening

Comment: @VocableTheory That error means exactly what it says: There are no rectangles in the list. Did you have at least one 'DrawObject' before? You can also access previous items via index: 'rectangles[x]'...

Comment: This is the code for drawing the drawing the object and changing its X and Y values,                                                                    'DrawObject()                                                                                                  ObjectX> 100                                                                                                 ObjectY> 100' Thats what I put to move it but i will do a little bit of messing around to see if I can see whats wrong

Comment: I did a debug think to print off how many objects are in the List of objects (rectangles), and it does say that there is one in the list, so I don't know what is wrong

Comment: And I typed `DrawObject()` once so I do not have a clue

Comment: @VocableTheory: Can you post your complete code as an update to the question so I can check it again?

Comment: @VocableTheory: That looks correct to me - did you try debug through the code? The only think I see at the moment is you used `DrawObject()` before and now you have `DrawObject>` in your code - did you change that in your "script" too?

Comment: I accidentally typed "DrawObject>" I meant "DrawObject()"

Comment: @VocableTheory: then I don't see anything wrong... Please try debug through the code to locate the exact problem.